# Java with information Flows, output to screen

Tags: java

I know that the audience of [JIF](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/jif/) is very small in numbers, but that's that Stack Overflow is for.
My question has to do with if anyone has a snipset with which I can declassify a String and send it as output to screen.
Example:

```
String data{Alice:} = "123";

output.println("this is it" + data);
```

<strike>note: more appropriate tag would be JIF, but I can not add tags yet.</strike>

Comment: For the enlightenment of the reader, this is JIF: http://www.cs.cornell.edu/jif/ . It's "a security-typed programming language that extends Java with support for information flow control and access control, enforced at both compile time and run time."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a partial answer. For the moment I am working in a code stub provided by a friend.
Here there is an output stream created with the lowest restrictions ({}, public):

```
PrintStream[{}] output = declassify(runtime.stdout(new label{}), {});
if (output == null) return;
```

Then the declassify(...) must be called to declassify to public and afterwards print.
Therefore later on in the program:

```
int{Alice:} iAlice = 3;
int aliceDec;
aliceDec = declassify(ziAlice, {});
output.println("aliceDec: " + aliceDec);
```